# Is it possible to use ExpressionEngine with an Oracle database?

Tags: database

I don't want to be forced to use Drupal. I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope - ExpressionEngine requires MySQL or a compatible drop-in replacement.

Comment: Seconded. EE will not work with Oracle.