# ExpressionEngine v.s. Database.Mangement System

Tags: database, mysql, system

I'm really confused! I've been trying non stop to connect to an Oracle database through ExpressionEngine throughout the last two weeks. I've finally given up when I saw a previous post([Is it possible to use ExpressionEngine with an Oracle database?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/22325)) that stated that EE will not work with Oracle.

the error I'm getting is 'driver not found' when I use the PDO oci or undeclared function connect_oci().

If this is true, why doesn't Oracle connect to EE?
Why can Filemaker connect to EE?
If this is true, is there a way to create documents that will allow Expression Engine to use Oracle?
Can EE only use MySQL and Mysqli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter **does** have a DB driver for oci8. Have you changed your driver? I mean, so much of the core is built around MySQL or equivalents.

You would have to do an **entire** rewrite of the Database class, as well as catch all manual MySQL commands and make sure they are Oracle-syntax correct. You would also have to do the same for all of your add-ons. This is really a futile (or epic) endeavor.

You are in such a better position create your own module and import an Oracle driver, and build your own Oracle ORM as a module. Or, even simplier, why the heck aren't you just doing a database migration from Oracle to MySQL or MariaDB???

**Edit**

Here is really the best resource for building your own modules/addons:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html

I can help you further, but only if you're building your own module. I'm a professional developer so you'll have to contract me if you want me to do it for you :) But if you can get it going, you can post new questions to the forum and we can help you.

Comment: Do you know where I can find tutorials or examples on building modules on EE and doing some of the things your recommending?

Comment: Also, to answer your question, I would be considered a guest to the database I would like to connect to.